# Adding an additional model relationships using build() on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently I have the following four models:

```
users <-- agency_memberships --> agencies
               |
               |
          agency_roles
```

`agency_memberships` is a join table, and `agency_roles` is a small lookup table with the roles :

```
ID    NAME
-----------
1     admin
2     editor
...
```

Before adding the `AgencyRole` model, when a user was created, if a param `create_agency = true`, then this was enough to create a new `Agency` (along the join table `AgencyMembership`).

```rb
# user_controller.rb

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.agencies.build(name: "Demo Agency") if params[:user][:create_agency]

  if @user.save!
    ...
end
```

However, now I need to add a valid `AgencyRole` before saving.

**Is it possible to do so with `.build()` or what is the Rails best practice to do so?**

Right now, I'm creating all relationships manually before saving, which works but isn't as compact:

```rb
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  if (params[:user][:create_agency])

    agency_name = params[:user][:agency_name]
    agency_role = AgencyRole.find_by(name: 'admin')
    
    @agency_membership = AgencyMembership.new(agency_role: @agency_role)
    @agency = Agency.new(name: agency_name)
    
    @agency_membership.agency = @agency
    @agency_membership.user = @user
    @agency_membership.agency_role = agency_role
    
    @user.agency_memberships << @agency_membership    
  end

  if @user.save!
    ...
end
```

**EdIT:** My model relationships are as follows:

```
class AgencyMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :agency
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :agency_role
end

class AgencyRole < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, presence: true
end

class Agency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :agency_memberships
  has_many :projects
  has_many :users, through: :agency_memberships
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :agency_memberships, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :agencies, through: :agency_memberships
end
```

Comment: How have you declared your active record associations in the 4 models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate and separate it from the controller, keep `thin controller fat model`, beside that you can use `autosave` in order to auto save association.

```rb
class AgencyMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :agency_role, autosave: true
end

class Agency < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :agency_membership, autosave: true
end

module BuildAgency
  def build_with_role(attributes = {}, &block)
    agency_role_name = attributes.delete(:role)

    agency = build(attributes, &block) # association: user - membership - agency
    
    # add role    
    agency_role = AgencyRole.find_by(name: agency_role_name)
    agency.agency_membership.agency_role = agency_role # autosave

    agency
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :agencies, autosave: true, :extend => BuildAgency

  def build_agency(attributes)
   new_agency = agencies.build_with_role(attributes)
   # ...
   new_agency
  end
end

# controller
def create
  if (params[:user][:create_agency])
    @user.build_agency(name: params[:user][:agency_name], role: params[:user][:agency_role])
  end
  if @user.save! # it'll save agencies since we set `autosave`
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quick question, what does attributes.delete do?
```agency_role_name = attributes.delete(:role)```

Comment: @Yuan-HaoChiang it'll extract `:role` out of `attributes` hash, then we can use the extracted value `role` to build agency role and also has the valid `attributes` hash to build association user-agency (since it does not contain `role` any more).

Comment: @Yuan-HaoChiang i updated my answer, moving the extract `:role` up :D